# Downloading content with python using variables

Tags: python, variables, download

I'm using the following line of code:

```
  urllib.urlretrieve(images, thisistest)
```

In images I have the URL of the image I want to download and thisistest contains the location.

The line of could would work if i entered in the data stored in the variables manually but wont work when it isn't.

The line without the variables however would be:

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png", "C:\temp")
```

Anyone any idea how I'd do it with the variables?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\main.py", line 68, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Python\main.py", line 65, in main
wp_dc.main(url)
File "C:\Python\wp_dc.py", line 69, in main
download_images(url, page)
File "C:\Python\wp_dc.py", line 39, in download_images
urllib.urlretrieve(i, thisistest)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 228, in retrieve
url = unwrap(toBytes(url))
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1057, in unwrap
url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

The code

```
#Finds all images in page
images = re.findall(r'src=".*http\://([^"]+)"', page)
location = os.path.abspath("C:/temp/coursework/")

#Get the filename
#For each in images
for i in images:
    #Set filename equal to the basename of i
    name = os.path.basename(i)

    #Concantenate the save location and filename
    thisistest = os.path.join(location, name)

    #Test the concantenation
    print 'Concantenation test', thisistest

    urllib.urlretrieve(i, thisistest)
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with what you have? There's no difference between a variable containing a string, and a string literal.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. Don't understand why it won't work but here is what the Python shell says, error added to original question.

Comment: `"C:\temp"` - the `\t` is a tab!  Use `"C:\\temp"` or `r"C:\temp"` or `"C:/temp"`

Comment: Show the code that generates the error!

Comment: #Finds all images in page
images = re.findall(r'src=".*http\://([^"]+)"', page)

#Get the filename
#For each in images
for i in images:
  #Set filename equal to the basename of i
  name = os.path.basename(i)

#Set the save location
location = os.path.abspath("C:/temp/coursework/")

#Concantenate the save location and filename
thisistest = location+"\\"+filename

#Test the concantenation
print 'Concantenation test', thisistest

urllib.urlretrieve(images, thisistest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your traceback indicates you are not doing what you said you were. This is the relevant code from that trace:

```
urllib.urlretrieve("images", "thisistest")
```

You are passing string literals, not variables. You should do what you originally said:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(images, thisistest)
```

**Edit**
OK, now this question is about something completely different. The problem is that `images` is a *list*, not a string, and you can't pass a list to urlretrieve. I suspect that you think you are doing something to fix this in the loop - but you aren't, you are just defining a local `name` variable that is then immediately overwritten and never referenced again anyway.

What you probably want to do is to move most of the code *inside* the loop:

```
location = os.path.abspath("C:/temp/coursework/")

for i in images:
    name = os.path.basename(i)
    thisistest = os.path.join(location, name)
    urllib.urlretrieve(i, thisistest)
```

Also note, these are precisely the sorts of problems that your instructor wants you to be solving yourself, as they are fostering the sort of logical thinking that you need in order to learn programming.

Comment: Didn't work when I added the speech marks, it gave me this error:     raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'images'

Comment: I didn't say to add speech marks. You were *already* adding them, hence the error. I said to take them away.

Comment: They weren't, I did not have the speech marks in the first place. Even without them it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, your stack trace clearly indicates that you did have them. If not, then you should post the *real* stack trace caused by running the code you have actually posted.

Comment: I updated the error on the main post, I think what has happened is that I copied the error log when I was testing if it worked with the speech marks?

Comment: Updated the indentation and moved the location out of the loop but it still doesn't work..

Comment: "Still doesn't work" isn't any good. Post your updated code, and the updated error.

Comment: **You need to learn to read more carefully**. As I say, attention to detail is *vital* in programming. `images` is still a list, which is why I used `i` in the call to `urlretrieve` in my updated code.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry about that.. My bad. Updated with new errors :/.

Comment: The problem has been because it never had http:// at the start of the link which threw up this error raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: www.google.com/